# Is there an easy way to validate schematron in xsd through bash commands

Tags: xml, xsd, schematron

I have a project where I need to add schematron to my xsd.
The problem is that I was using xmllint which does not allow to validate schematron, I found other solutions like using xsltproc and iso-schematron but this obliges me to add the folder iso-schematron to my project.

Do you have a simpler solution to validate schematron with bash commands?

I used [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10384788/validating-xsd-schema-with-schematron-and-xsltproc) and I wanted to test using [this process](http://www.topologi.com/resources/schtrn_xsd_paper.html#Processing) but it seems more complicated than my first solution.

XSD code :

```
  <xs:element name="worker">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:appinfo>
        <sch:pattern name="Testing schematron" xmlns:sch="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron">
          <sch:rule context="worker">
            <sch:assert test="id>2"
              You have to respect de schema.
            </sch:assert>
        </sch:pattern>
      </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="id" type="xs:token"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

xml code :

```xml
  <worker>
    <id>3</id>
  </worker>
```

Solution bash :

```sh
echo XSD validation
xsltproc iso-schematron-xslt/ExtractSchFromXSD.xsl my_xsd_schema.xsd > schema.sch
xsltproc iso-schematron-xslt/iso_dsdl_include.xsl schema.sch > step1.xsl
xsltproc iso-schematron-xslt/iso_abstract_expand.xsl step1.xsl > step2.xsl
xsltproc iso-schematron-xslt/iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl step2.xsl > step3.xsl
xsltproc step3.xsl my_xml_code.xml
rm schema.sch
rm step1.xsl
rm step2.xsl
rm step3.xsl
```